# getting server could not serialize the result requested. Server error on using .explain() step in gremlin

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

am getting a serialisation issue when using explain() step for traversals

> Server could not serialize the result requested. Server error -
>   Error during serialization: Class is not registered:
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.TraversalExplanation
>       Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.TraversalExplanation.class);.
>   Note that the class must be serializable by the client and server for
>   proper operation.

what are the steps to register a class in gremlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you might be using an older version of TinkerPop. There was a time when that class was not registered with Gryo and it would lead to errors like this. I assume you just want the output of the `TraversalExplanation` and not the object itself so a simple workaround would be to simply `toString()` your result.

```
g.V().out().explain().toString()
```